# Issue when trying to send pdf file to FastAPI through XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, fastapi

**Context**

I have a pdf file that i get thanks to drag'n drop on my web client. (the file was obtains on the 'drop' event thank to `event.dataTransfer.files[0]`). The file is a valid file because i can exploit it thank to a javascript pdf library.

I want to send this file to an API that i wrote with an XMLHttpRequest. The API is a python API wrote with `fastAPI` library.

**Problem**

I can't manage to catch the file on the python API...

**Environment**

My web interface is local hosted on a python server. My API is also local hosted on an uvicorn server with **enabled CORS policy**. I have the specific "route" :

> localhost:port/token

that give me the state of the API (if the API is "ready"). "token" simply is an access token.

I'm able to perform an XMLHtppRequest on this route from my web client and get the JSON response without any issues.

Here is the javascript request:

```
// Get the API status
export function pingApi() {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // Request response treatment
    xhr.onload = function () { 
        if (this.status === 200) {
            let obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            console.log(obj);
        }
    }

    // Send the request
    xhr.open("GET", API_STATUS_ENDPOINT + "/" + API_TOKEN, true);
    xhr.send();
}
```

But when i try to send the request to the API i get some errors logged more behind.

Here the request to the API :

```
// Send the request to the pdfclass API
export function sendPdf(file) {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let formData = new FormData();
    
    // Request response treatment
    xhr.onload = function () { 
        if (this.status === 200) {
            let obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            console.log(obj);
        }
    }

    // Create the form data object
    formData.append("pdf", file);

    xhr.open("POST", API_PDF_ENDPOINT + "/" + API_TOKEN, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');

    // Send the request
    xhr.send(formData);
}
```

As you can see i'm using a formData to send my pdf file.

**Python API**

I show here the details of the python API route:

```
# Send a pdf document via form
        @self.api.post("/uploadPdfForm/{token}")
        async def upload_pdf_form(token: str, request: Request):
            # Authorized token required
            if self.is_authorized(token):

                # Get the form object
                form = await request.form()
                # Get the uploaded file
                uploaded_pdf = form['pdf']
       ...
```

And here is the **python** error log i got :

> ...
> File "D:[OpenStudio]\Workspace\api-pdfclass\lib\pdfclassapi.py", line 89,
> in upload_pdf_form
> form = await request.form()

> File "C:\Users\theop\miniconda3\envs\trainer\lib\site-packages\starlette\requests.py",
> line 239, in form
> self._form = await multipart_parser.parse()

> File "C:\Users\theop\miniconda3\envs\trainer\lib\site-packages\starlette\formparsers.py",
> line 181, in parse
> parser = multipart.MultipartParser(boundary, callbacks)

> File "C:\Users\theop\miniconda3\envs\trainer\lib\site-packages\multipart\multipart.py",
> line 1042, in **init**
> self.boundary = b'\r\n--' + boundary

> TypeError: can't concat NoneType to bytes

I also got a "CORS policy" issue on my web client console but i really think it's because the request isn't correctly treated on the API side because CORS is allow on the API server.

**What i tried**

I'm stuck on this file transfer for 3 days now.. i tried a lot of things like using jquery, not using formData, trying to encode my file, trying to directly use Form of FastAPI in my API...

I don't really understand why is this request not working. Any help will be appreciate a lot

Comment: Try and remove the line that sets the `Content-Type` header. A multipart upload _needs_ a boundary specified in that request header, but by setting it yourself (and without one), you are probably overwriting the one the browser would automatically provide based on that FormData is getting used.

Comment: Man.. U literally saved me ! Oh man that was because the header was overwritten.. Thank a lot everything instantly work well after i removed this line.  [EDIT] please write an answer that i can accept as solution man

Comment: Alright, I made the comment into a quick answer, so you have something to mark as solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the line that sets the `Content-Type` header.

A multipart upload *needs* a boundary specified in that request header, but by setting it yourself (and without one), you are overwriting the one the browser would automatically provide based on that FormData is getting used.